# rails3+ruby1.9.2p0+ubuntu+CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error with CSV in (Rails3, ruby 1.9.2p0, ubuntu)

when i use CSV.generate { |csv| ... }  i get the error

error in generate - worng number of arguements(0 for 1)

when i use CSV.generate({}) { |csv| ... } i get the error

TypeError cant convert hash into string

please, can you help me with the soluton for this.

code i used

csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [
  "S_No",
  "User ID",
  "Password"
  ]

@password_array.each do |password|
    csv << [
    @user_name,
    @user_id,
    @password]
  end

end

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CSV.generate method expects a string as the first argument.  It can be an empty string if you want, so try this:

```
csv_data = CSV.generate("") { |csv| ... }
```

For more information, read the [documentation of the Ruby CSV class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV.html#M000182).

Comment: this case i still get error as Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory)